# WebSphere 7 org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator <init> org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, apache-axis, websphere-7

This is a strange problem.  I have an ***existing*** JEE project that **is** and **has been** in production on WebSphere 7.  It is a multi-module EAR file.  It has 2 WARs and 1 shared Java project.  Most of it is Spring 4 based, but we have some web services  we host using axis2 (1.5.4).  This project **does not** use Maven.  It does use a WebSphere deployment.xml (in the EAR) with the warClassloaderPolicy="SINGLE" and the classloader mode="PARENT_**LAST**".  This controls the classloader policies for this EAR.  All the jar files that the Java project and the WARs rely on are stored at the EAR level and referenced at the module level via the manifest files.  That all works fine and has for several years.

Now I was trying to convert this project to a Maven project after all these years.  Initially, I left the deployment.xml file settings as they always have been.  But with these settings I was getting:

```
java.lang.VerifyError at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl "org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller".
```

After much googling on this site and all around and trying 50,000 things, I tried one thing, which worked for **most** of the app.  I switched the classloader mode to "PARENT_**FIRST**" and all of a sudden the WAR that exclusively uses Spring 4 worked.  It started up without error and I was able to run it.

But, the other WAR which hosts the axis2 web services started getting the error:

```
org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator <init> org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException....Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException....Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException
```

This class (org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException) is in both the **compile** and **runtime** classpath.  In eclipse I can see it in the "**Maven Dependencies**" library that the m2e eclipse plugin creates from the POM files.  I can also see this jar in the WebSphere runtime module classpath inspector (it shows up in there 3 times!  Once under each WAR and once just in a list from the Maven repository location.)

One thing of note is that I've configured the project with a parent POM, where most of the dependencies are declared at the parent and then are inherited for each of the modules.  In the EAR project, the POM is using the maven-ear-plugin with skinnyWars=true.  However, it appears the skinnyWars directive is not respected when the m2e eclipse plugin deploys the EAR into the local WebSphere server (that is evident because I see these jars showing up in the classpath 3 times).  But when I create an EAR using the Maven build, the EAR comes out correctly with each jar only showing up in the EAR one time.

This is my last hope to post something here and see if someone has an idea for something to try, otherwise I can't think of anything else to try.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you need to run with a single class loader for all the WAR modules, other than convenience?  If not, you could rework the application in order to allow you to run PARENT_FIRST in the Spring WAR and PARENT_LAST in the Axis2 WAR.

If that's not an option for some reason, the path of least resistance might be to go back to PARENT_LAST and remove some libraries from the app or module.  The VerifyError generally occurs if you're running with PARENT_LAST and have a library in the app that is also present in the server - in this case, the exception looks like it's coming out of JAXB, so you might want to see if simply removing JAXB (and perhaps JAXP, if present, since it's heavily used by JAXB) from the application resolves the issue with your default setup.

You could also stick with PARENT_FIRST and move the Axis2 jars to an shared library with an isolated class loader, associated with the app.  An isolated shared library would make just the stuff in the shared library PARENT_LAST, so you can avoid the VerifyError and still get PARENT_LAST for Axis2.  The issue in the PARENT_FIRST case appears to be because you're picking up WebSphere's copy of Axis2 but somehow have a dependency inserted from your app's copy - the failing class load is occurring in a server-level loader, so it doesn't see the copy in your app.

Comment: Hi Jarid, Thanks for the help.  No particular reason for single classloader.  In fact, went into the WAS admin console and modified the WAR classloader policy to **'Class loader for each WAR file in application'** (MODULE), then 'Manage Modules' for the WAR that has Axis2 and set class loading order to '... local classloader first' and got verifyerror on OMContainer.getChildrenWithName.  

I will take a look at your suggestion about PARENT_LAST and removing libraries.  I did try some of that previously.I thought JAXB would be needed 4 Spring mod

With regards to library, I'd prefer not too

Comment: JAXB may have been needed at one point, but it's been a part of Java EE/SE for awhile now, so you usually won't need to bring your own.

Comment: Now, I've removed jaxb implementation that axis2-jaxws was pulling in via transitive dependency.  Now getting java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.JAXBContextImpl incompatible with javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext

Comment: Do you still have a JAXB API in the app?  You can't include the API without the implementation.

Comment: Well, now I've removed the JAXB API and getting 

"javax.xml.namespace.QName does not have a no-arg default constructor this problem is related to the following location: at javax.xml.namespace.QName at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement <my company's package name>.ObjectFactory.createQName(javax.xml.namespace.QName) at <my company's package name>.ObjectFactory"

I will try to google that message...

Comment: Well... It appears that my suggestions may have been barking up the wrong tree, because it's looking like your code may actually have a dependency on a specific JAXB version.  In that case, this is a bit trickier a set of dependencies than I'd thought.  Just curious, have you diffed the two copies of the EAR (pre-Maven and post-Maven) to see if there are jars in different locations between the two?

Comment: Good idea - I'll check

Comment: By the way, the EAR will be in a different format because Maven is building it - since I'm using 'skinnyWars', it is putting all the shared Jars (defined at the parent level) in the EAR/lib directory, then the Maven generated manifest.mf refers to those jars.  If dependencies are declared at the WAR module level, then those jars are simply placed in the WEB-INF/lib by Maven when building the EAR.

Comment: Well, I added a maven dependency exclusion for every jar found in the new Maven generated EAR that was not in the old EAR.  Now it is starting up without error and working.  I excluded a total of 37 jars that were added by Maven that were not in the non-Maven jars... Wow...  Thanks for your help Jarid!